# Verb form used for a to-do list for oneself?

Tags: verbs

What verb form is usually used in Japanese for a to-do list for oneself?

I want to start writing my to-do list in Japanese. In English, I would typically write my to-do list as actionable commands to myself (e.g., "Email Dave", "Vacuum the living room"). So I would expect to use something like [the Japanese version of the command form](https://www.tofugu.com/japanese-grammar/verb-command-form-ro/). However, I don't know if giving such commands to yourself seems unnatural in Japanese. Or if there are more natural forms for writing to-do lists. Are there any forms that seem the most common or natural for this purpose?

Comment: Actual examples: https://support.apple.com/ja-jp/HT205890, https://time-space.kddi.com/mobile/20200507/2900

Comment: Is it really the command form that you use in English or rather the ground form ("[to] email Dave", "[to] vacuum the living room")? I am wondering because e.g. in German, where the forms are clearly distinguishable from each other, you use the ground form ("Milch einkaufen") rather than the command form ("Kaufe Milch ein"). But I am not a native speaker, so I'm just guessing.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The plain dictionary form is used, but する is commonly omitted when the verb is a suru-verb. Simple noun phrases can be used, too. Examples:

- デイブにメール(する)
- 部屋に掃除機をかける
- 卵を買う
- ホテルの予約 or ホテルを予約(する)