# What's the idiomatic tense of verb to use in a TODO list?

Tags: verbs

Suppose I have a TODO list with items meant to be read by myself in the future. Items include things like

- Buy milk
- Get groceries

and so forth. If this TODO list were translated to Japanese, what would the idiomatic tense of the verbs be?

- ミルクを買え (imperative, since TODO items are technically commands to oneself?)
- ミルクを買おう (volitional, to make it more encouraging?)
- ミルクを買う (non-past?)

I assume that since the TODO list is primarily meant to be read by one's self, no Keigo or formal conjugations would be required?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Verb form used for a to-do list for oneself?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/96154/verb-form-used-for-a-to-do-list-for-oneself)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

People usually won't use keigo in any sort of *note to self*, yes.

So if you're talking about shopping lists, most people will simply list itens in it; since it's a shopping list there's no need to write ～を買う anywhere. Here's an exemple I've found online by googling 買い物リスト:
[image: shopping list]

Now for a ToDo list, people usually use 辞書形{じしょけい} (the dictionary form), e.g. 牛乳を買う or ホテルの予約をする, ゴミを出す. This is what I found googling for やることリスト:
[image: todo list]

命令形{めいれいけい} (imperative) would only be used in a note to someone else (hierarchically below self), not to oneself.

Comment: You wouldn't use the 命令形 in a list like this but I feel 「落ち着け自分」 and the like are common enough

Comment: @Angelos By 落ち着け自分 do you mean something like a "command given to yourself, to calm yourself down"?

Answer (score 3):

`ミルクを買え` and `ミルクを買おう` would be extremely uncommon though not wrong. `ミルクを買う` is fine but most people will probably shorten it to `ミルク買う` or just `ミルク`.  You could also say `ミルク購入` but in this specific case it would be uncommon because it's cumbersome to write `購`.

Other examples would be:

- 部屋掃除 or 部屋掃除する
- 洗濯物の取り込み or 洗濯物取り込む
- 鍵返却 or カギ返す

Another possible form is ミルク買っとく which is close to `ミルクを買え` or `ミルクを買おう` but more common because it fits well with a TODO list (it's odd to say "Buy milk" or "Let's buy milk" to yourself, but "Better have milk" is a bit more natural to tell yourself IMO)